# Google Map is asking for API V2 and not showing Map after adding places Api Android

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am facing a strange situation, My app is in production mode and recently I added the feature of google API for finding places and map them over map. I am using a different web API for calling places which are returning json data.
API is something like this -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="lat","lon"&radius=&type=atm&keyword=&key=AIzaSyEXampleApi";
```

I am using a fragment for the map where I don't have googlemap.xml stuff I just added API key in the manifest file and it was working fine previously.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="api_key" />
```

When I was running it via android studio it was fine now when I have published over Playstore map is gone. neither map is showing nor autosuggestion for places is working.i have checked sha1 placed it over google console.

Error Showing - `Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.07-21 01:50:04.771 25734-26650/? E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.Ensure that the following Android Key exists:API Key:AIzaSyCB-------Sample----Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>):`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the SHA1 fingerprint of your release keys to your Google Developer Console (just like you did for the debug key). Check out this link to see how you can get the SHA1 fingerprint from the release key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert